# MVC Active Directory Authentication by Organizational Unit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, active-directory, windows-authentication, organizational-unit

I want to recycle AD security in my .NET MVC web application and have virtually no local security tables, if possible.

I can easily achieve this using the `Authorize` tag:

```
[Authorize(Roles="GoldDigger")]
public ActionResult Go(int companyKey)
{
    var something = GetData(companyKey);
    return something;
}
```

However, I have users who have access to multiple companies (Acme, StoreCo, etc.), and are `GoldDigger`s in some but not all of those companies. Let's say I create an Active Directory OU Container for each company, so I have the following AD role structure:

- `NTWRK\Acme\GoldDigger`
- `NTWRK\StoreCo\GoldDigger`
- `NTWRK\PetCo\GoldDigger`
- `NTWRK\Megalomart\GoldDigger`

To my knowledge I can no longer use the `Authorize` tag because the AD role required is determined by the value of the CompanyKey parameter.

What are my best options at this point to avoid adding the following to the top of every controller method? Is it possible to force the context of the authorization to a particular (non-hard-coded) organizational unit at the beginning or earlier in the session?

```
if (!AuthenticateAdRoleByCompany(companyKey, "Role Name Here"))
{
    Explode();
    return;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20707758/authorization-using-active-directory-role-provider-mvc4

Comment: @FrankFajardo: What is the difference between that and what I listed above?

Comment: Have something like `[Authorize(Roles="NTWRK\\Acme\\GoldDigger")]`

Comment: But like I said, the `Acme` bit is dependent on the `companyKey` parameter.